# angular 2 barebones project in visual studio 2013

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2013, gulp, systemjs

I'm having trouble getting an angular 2 project set up in Visual Studio 2013 (note needs to be 2013 not 2015).  I've been looking online and can't find answers.  I want to use gulp and system js. Does anyone have a working starter project (Hello World) in Visual Studio 2013 with angular 2, gulp, typescript, and system js?

Answer (score 0):

Try [generator-dotnetcore-angular2-starterkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-dotnetcore-angular2-starterkit) over at NPM

or [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/) which uses the Visual studio template extension